# How to request a different location after a job offer

Tags: recruitment, human-resources

Last month I applied for a customer service job at Airport A and Airport B. After I applied to the same position at two different locations last week, I received an interview call from Airport A and they have offered me the job.

But I would more prefer to work in Airport B which is closer to where I live. At the same time I got an email from Airport B stating:

> Due to the high demand of the particular role recruitment process is
>   taking longer than expected

They have also confirmed that my application is still being processed.

What I want I would like to request of them is whether they can offer me the job offer at Airport B instead of Airport A because the same agency is recruiting for both locations.

Comment: You could always just turn down the Stanstead offer and wait to get the same offer from Heathrow. Just be prepared to possibly lose out on both offers, though :O. As for asking, you could always ask, but just be prepared for them to say no to this. A more "valid" reason may help, but the decision really is not ours, so it's hard to say :/.

Comment: Do you mean the SOP to do so? Then you need to ask your recruiting agency. But if you mean just asking, you could just ask them the same way you had asked us.

Comment: I draft the latter for them could you please check the letter.

Comment: You may post it but whether or not anyone will proofread it for you is a different question.... Also note that if this is about proofreading, perhaps the [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask? But even they won't help proofread....

Comment: First of all, I do my sincere apology, the reason why I am writing you this letter to ask whether you can give me the same job offer at Heathrow Airport since I apply for the same position at Heathrow. I have been contacted by the Heathrow team due to the high demand of the particular role recruitment process is taking longer than expected and they have confirmed that my application is still processed. Please if you can do me a need full help it would be appreciated as I am not planning to relocate due to several reason.

Comment: Please see my comment before your post. I have edited it.

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to request them to transfer my application to Heathrow or shall i wait Heathrow recruiters to call me for an interview.

Comment: The latter. You have too little information to make any sort of decision.

Answer (score 2):

I guess technically you could accept the offer you've had at Stansted and then wait to see if you get anywhere with the Heathrow position.

If these positions are for the same company / organisation then you might be able to get a transfer in time but for now I'd suggest you take the job you have been offered. Better than risking losing out altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you would be willing to work at Stansted if you do not get the position at Heathrow, then accept the offer.  If you then get an offer from Heathrow, accept that and either quit or explain that you can't take the job (depending on whether or not you've already started working).

If you really don't want to work at Stansted, turn it down and hope you get the job at Heathrow.

Do not ask if you can have the job at Heathrow - you have already applied, so they are aware that you want a job there.